# I cant disable shallow routing in next js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I set shallow routing true for once and after that everything is in shallow routing mode and I cant disable it.

```
 router.push("/products?page=2",undefined, {
            shallow : false
 })
```

Comment: Standard routing like `router.push("/products?page=2")` may yield the behavior that you want. Also checking out the shallow copy caveats could help: https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/shallow-routing#caveats

Comment: `next/router` will not use shallow routing if `shallow` isn't set to true on that specific call. Can you please clarify the unexpected behaviour you're seeing? What do you mean by shallow routing?